# Does the unique constraint in Postgres create an index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, runtime

Let's say that I have a table that looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
   product_no integer UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   name text,
   price numeric
);
```

Then if I insert values into the table, will postgres (or any similar DBMS) actually check through each row of the table or is an index automatically created? If there is no index, this becomes expensive really fast [O(N!)].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.  Postgres checks that the `product_no` has not already been inserted.  It does so by checking an *index*, not the individual rows.

The unique constraint is implemented using an index, so checking for duplication is O(log n) not O(n).

Comment: Ok. But what about on a distributed system where there are multiple computers storing many many rows of data?

Comment: @ArielA . . . Should be the same basic idea, using a distributed index -- it depends what you mean by "distributed" system.  The `unique` index can be partitioned, for instance.

Comment: @ArielA A partitioned unique index must contain the partitioning key. If you shard across multiple databases, the same restriction does apply.